# Contagem de relacionamentos no Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

No Laravel 4, não temos o método presente no Laravel 5.2 >= chamado `withCount`. Esse `withCount` é responsável por adicionar ao `SELECT` a contagem de itens relacionados a entidade atual.

Por exemplo:

```
  $u = Usuario::withCount('posts')->first();
  var_dump($u->posts_count); // int(5)
```

Porém no meu caso, estou dando manutenção em um sistema que fiz há uns 3 anos atrás, onde eu ainda utilizava o Laravel 4. E a solução que tínhamos naquela época, sem escrever SQL na mão, era chamar um `count` para cada item relacionado.

Assim:

```
 foreach($usuarios as $usuario) {
      echo $usuario->posts()->count();
 }
```

O problema disso é que, pra cada iteração, o Laravel vai chamar um `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE usuario_id = ?`, e eu imagino que numa iteração de 500 linhas, isso vai ferrar meu servidor de banco de dados.

E no meu caso, creio também que seja inviável migrar o projeto do Laravel 4 para o 5.

Sendo assim, pergunto:

- Como posso carregar antecipadamente (eager loader) a contagem de itens relacionados a uma entidade (model) no Laravel 4?

Comment: Você precisa carregar esse contador de todos usuários em determinada página? Senão poderia paginar e carregar X resultados a cada interação. Caso precise carregar tudo, qual a possibilidade de criar um atributo para o usuário e salvar/atualizar no banco o numero de posts que ele possui ao invés de rodar o count sempre?

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer criar um atributo para salvar no branco viola as regras da normalização. Eu gostaria de uma solução próxima ao `withCount` mesmo

Comment: Isso tu consegue resolver com eagerload. 
Usuario::with('posts')->get();

Comment: @cau não. Isso aí traz todos os registros, e quando tive 10.000 registros no relacionamento ferrou minha aplicação (sem contar que fazer isso é uma gambiarra sem tamanho)

Comment: Isso aqui funcionou no Laravel 5. Não tentei no 4.

$users = User::join('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->groupBy('users.id')->get(['users.id', 'users.name', \DB::raw('count(posts.id) as posts')]);

Jeffrey Way:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-query-with-count-of-objects-in-a-one-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra ficar registrado aqui no site: para resolver essa situação, eu tive que usar uma ideia meio mirabolante. Eu fiz uma implementação quase que manual usando alguns recursos presente na classe `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` e `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

No meu caso, eu tinha o model `Remessa` e cada remessa tem `x` solicitações. Eu precisaria de algo similar ao código abaixo, caso eu estivesse no Laravel 5.

```
 Remessa::withCount('solicitacoes')->get()
```

No caso, pra fazer isso, eu criei um `scope` no model `Remessa` que gerava a subquery que eu passava para o `SELECT` de `Remessa`, assim:

```
public function scopeQuantidadeSolicitacoes($query, $as = 'solicitacoes_quantidade', Closure $callback = null)
{
    $subQuery = Solicitacao::whereRaw('remessas.id = solicitacoes.remessa_id')->selectRaw('COUNT(*)');

    $callback && $callback($subQuery);

    $subSelectExpression = DB::raw(sprintf('(%s) as %s', $subQuery->toSql(), $as));

    // Caso não exista um `SELECT` especificado, coloca * por padrão
    if ($query->getQuery()->columns === null)
    {
        $query->select('*');
    }

    $query->addBinding($subQuery->getQuery()->getBindings(), 'select');

    return $query->addSelect($subSelectExpression);
}
```

Para usar é só fazer assim:

```
Remessa::quantidadeSolicitacoes('qtd_solicitacoes')
        ->quantidadeSolicitacoes('qtd_solicitacoes_bloqueadas', function ($query) {
            $query->where('bloqueado', '=', 1);
        })
        ->get();
```

O resultado é o mesmo praticamente do Laravel 5.